# how can I pass the checkbox value from one form to another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to design two forms. One form offer a checkbox and a 'confirm' button for user to select, another form display a message box to detect once the user check the checkbox and click the confirm button.

```
public Form1()
{
    if (Form2.confirmButtonClicked == true)
    {
        if(Form2.checkbox1.checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You check the checkbox");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public Form2()
{
    if (checkbox.checked == true)
    {
        return checkbox.checked;
    }
}
```

Sorry I am new to c#, and my question might too simple to you. Please kindly teach me because I had read those examples from online and do not know how to troubleshoot this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd kindly advise you to describe the question more briefly.
Also I'd recommend to not compare boolean values with true or false like you did here: `Form2.confirmButtonClicked == true` instead you can just write `Form2.confirmButtonClicked` and get the same result. Moreover, you can get rid of one of the if statements & get same check with only one: `Form2.confirmButtonClicked && Form2.checkbox1.checked`
My question is does your code compile or you have build errors with the code provided above?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem a long time ago.
To solve this issue, I wrote a class file for this work and published it on GitHub so that others can use it as well.

It is very easy to use, I explained in the repository (use my project in github)

https://github.com/sapurtcomputer30/DynamicFormAction

But note this class file is now responsive for WindowsForm
In using this file, you do not need to change the modifier controls, and you can move any data, including text photos, other data between each form, as an dynamic array.

Example

The form in which there is a checkbox (example Form1):

```
this.Action(checkbox1.Cheked);
```

In other forms :

```
var form1 = new Form1();
bool checkBoxValue = form1.GetFormAction()[0];
```

In this class, I have not considered the data type so that any data type can be moved between forms
for example :

```
this.Action("data",123,true,ModelClass);
```

When calling :

```
string data = form2.Action()[0];
int number = form2.Action[1];
bool b = form2.Action[2];
ModelClass c = form2.Action()[3];
```

In addition, there are other ways

1. You can change the access of the checkbox modifier to public mode and manipulate it (the simplest case)
2. Create a class file that contains a predefined variable (consider the class and the static variable) and move the data with this class into the check box.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to accomplish this task, in the child form, setup a `readonly` property which represents the Checked state of the CheckBox. Place two buttons on the child form, one for confirm, one for cancel and set each of buttons `DialogResult` as per the image below. In the main form, check the DialogResult.

**Child form**

```
namespace PassingDataBetweenFormsSimple
{
    public partial class ConfirmForm : Form
    {
        public bool Confirmed => AgreeCheckBox.Checked;
        public ConfirmForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

In the **main form**, Debug.WriteLine is used to see if the child form property Confirmed is true or false, feel free to use a MessageBox but seems prudent to react with code rather than showing a MessageBox.

```
private void ShowConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var confirmForm = new ConfirmForm();

    try
    {
        if (confirmForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (confirmForm.Confirmed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Yes");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No");
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        confirmForm.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]